Tropical polynomials, distributivity, the integers, and bases
I'm very much a novice in the world of tropical polynomials, but I find the topic fascinating. Recently I've been pondering tropical analogs of classical polynomials, and as somewhat an offshoot of this I've been thinking about how those polynomials are represented. In the classical polynomial ring, for instance, the distributive law gives $(x+1)^2=x^2+x+x+1$, and then by combining terms we get $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$. But tropically, we have $(x\oplus1)^{\circ2}=2\min(x, 1)$ $=\min(2x, 2)$ $=x^{\circ2}\oplus2$. Of course, the core of the issue here is that $x\oplus x\neq 2\otimes x$, but it feels like there's an implicitly fundamental role being played by $\mathbb{Z}$ here in the classical case that has no real analog.
Obviously this isn't something that's generally thought about in tropical geometry, since there's something of a canonical form for tropical polynomials: $\min(a_0x+b_0, a_1x+b_1, \ldots)$. But has the notion of bases been looked at for tropical polynomials at all? In particular, I'm curious as to whether any tropical analog of the Bezier polynomials/basis has been looked at.
